# Не работает PHPMailer, ошибка с подключением файла Exception.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer

Не работает PHPMailer, ни локально, ни на хостинге. На хостинге, выдает ошибку 500
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В **error_log** пишет что не может найти Exception.php, пытался по разному указать к нему путь, ничего не помогает

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: Could not instantiate mail function. in /home/s/seventimes/AlenkaDi/public_html/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php:1943\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/s/seventimes/AlenkaDi/public_html/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1664): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->mailSend('Date: Tue, 21 J...', '\xD0\x94\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBD\xD0\xB8\xD0\xB8\xD0\xBB 79...')\n#1 /home/s/seventimes/AlenkaDi/public_html/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1500): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend()\n#2 /home/s/seventimes/AlenkaDi/public_html/send_mail.php(23): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /home/s/seventimes/AlenkaDi/public_html/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 1943

Прикладываю код, заранее спасибо за помощь.

P.S. Вместо css, написал php.

```js
const form = document.forms["form"];
const formArr = Array.from(form);
const validFormArr = [];
const button = form.elements["button"];

formArr.forEach((el) => {
  if (el.hasAttribute("data-reg")) {
    el.setAttribute("is-valid", "0");
    validFormArr.push(el);
  }
});

form.addEventListener("input", inputHandler);
form.addEventListener("submit", formCheck); // обработка кнопки "Отправить"

function inputHandler({
  target
}) {
  if (target.hasAttribute("data-reg")) {
    inputCheck(target);
  }
}

function inputCheck(el) {
  const inputValue = el.value;
  const inputReg = el.getAttribute("data-reg");
  const reg = new RegExp(inputReg);
  if (reg.test(inputValue)) {
    el.setAttribute("is-valid", "1");
    el.style.border = "2px solid rgb(0, 196, 0)";
  } else {
    el.setAttribute("is-valid", "0");
    el.style.border = "2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0)";
  }
}

function formCheck(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // блокируем input
  const allValid = []; // создаем массив валидных значений
  validFormArr.forEach((el) => {
    allValid.push(el.getAttribute("is-valid")); // проверяем каждое поле
  });
  const isAllValid = allValid.reduce((acc, current) => { // проверяем, чтобы все было правильно
    return acc && current;
  });
  if (!Boolean(Number(isAllValid))) {
    alert("Заполните поля правильно!"); // если не правильно - сообщение пользователю
    return;
  }
  formSubmit(); // если правильно - отправляем данные
}

async function formSubmit() {
  const data = serializeForm(form); // получаем данные формы
  const response = await sendData(data); // отправляем данные на почту
  if (response.ok) {
    let result = await response.json(); // если ответ OK отвечает пользователю
    alert(result.message); // .. что данные отправлены
    formReset(); // сбрасываем поля формы
  } else {
    alert("Код ошибки: " + response.status); // если not OK - показываем код ошибки
  }
}

function serializeForm(formNode) { // формируем данные формы
  return new FormData(form);
}

async function sendData(data) {
  return await fetch("send_mail.php", { // отправляем в скрипт send_mail.php
    method: "POST", // методом POST
    body: data,
  });
}

function formReset() { // сброс полей формы
  form.reset();
  validFormArr.forEach((el) => {
    el.setAttribute("is-valid", 0);
    el.style.border = "none";
  });
}
```

```css
<?php

require(__DIR__."/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php");
require (__DIR__."/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php");

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); /* Создаем объект MAIL */
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8"; /* Задаем кодировку UTF-8 */

$name = $_POST["name"]; /* Принимаем имя пользователя с формы .. */
$phone = $_POST["phone"]; /* Телефон */

$body = $name . ' ' . $phone;
$theme = "[Заявка с формы]";
 
$mail->addAddress("seventimezzz@gmail.com"); /* Здесь введите Email, куда отправлять */

$mail->Subject = $theme;
$mail->Body = $body;

$mail->send();
 
?>



/* Принимаем имя пользователя с формы .. */

$phone=$_POST["phone"];

/* Телефон */

$body=$name . ' ' . $phone;
$theme="[Заявка с формы]";
$mail->addAddress("seventimezzz@gmail.com");

/* Здесь введите Email, куда отправлять */

$mail->Subject=$theme;
$mail->Body=$body;
$mail->send();
?>
```

```html
<form action="send_mail.php" class="popup__box" id="form" name="form" method="POST">
  <div class="popup__text">Оставьте ваше имя и телефон и мы обязательно свяжемся с вами.<br> С нами можно связаться по телефону <span class="popup__numer-color">+79876791060</span></div>
  <div class="popup__input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" id="name" data-reg="^[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*$" class="howWeWork__input popup__input" value="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="phone" id="phone" data-reg="^((\+7|7|8)+([0-9]){10})$" class="howWeWork__input popup__input" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="howWeWork__agree-box">
    <input type="checkbox" class="howWeWork__agree-checkbox" name="" id="">
    <div class="howWeWork__agree-text">Нажимая отправить, вы соглашаетесь на обработку персональных данных</div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" value="Отправить" id="button" name="button" class="howWeWork__btn">Оставить заявку</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Может сначала надо __подключить__ файлы, а потом использовать use?

Comment: `/public_htmlPHPMailer/` тут отсутствует слэш, потому что `__DIR__` возвращает директорию без конечного слэша

Comment: Попробовал в начале подключить файлы, а затем использовать use, не помогло. Сделал как вы сказали   и теперь с Exception все хорошо, но теперь какие то проблемы с PHPMail. Я перезалил свежий error_log и send_mail.php